# How to execute a code block, only when no exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a part of the code where I want to display a message containing the Exception details in JOptionPane, if an exception is caught. That exception error is being displayed correctly.

I also want to display a "Successful" message, only if the intended process is successful and no Exception is caught. But this Successful message is being displayed even though there is an exception caught.

Observe the JOptionPane statements in and outside catch block in the below code.

```
private void submitBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    saveToDataBase();        
}                                         

public void saveToDataBase(){
    try{
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    String uname = "root";
    String pass = "password";
    String query = "insert into emp values (";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    query += idTextField.getText() + "," + fNameTextField.getText() + "," + lNameTextField.getText() + ")";
     st.executeUpdate(query);
    } 

   catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The data has been saved successfully!!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

Comment: just add a `return` at the end of the catch block (or put the second `showMessage` inside the try block - despite this last is not so good IMO -  actually there is a lot of code that does not *need* to be inside the try block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

First return in case of an exception

```
 catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
```

the second move the success message into the try block

```
   try{
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    String uname = "root";
    String pass = "password";
    String query = "insert into emp values (";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    query += idTextField.getText() + "," + fNameTextField.getText() + "," + lNameTextField.getText() + ")";
     st.executeUpdate(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The data has been saved successfully!!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } 

   catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Move this line into your `try-catch` block

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The data has been saved successfully!!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Since this line was excluded from your `try-catch` - after the exception is being handled the same line is getting executed again.